# Calculating the range of $f(x)=\sqrt{2x-6}$.

Tags: functions

Please tell me how to calculate the range of $f(x)=\sqrt{2x-6}$?

The solution in my math note says that the range of $f(x)$ is  $\lbrace y\in\mathbb{R}:y\ge 0\rbrace$.

As I followed this [link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110530202805AA4sIkL%22link%22)  and do the sum, it gives me the range as $-\infty$ to $\infty$.
Please help me.

Comment: Your link has been deleted, and it is a good thing. Follow [this link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8ziigxskhe) instead. Do you know that the range of $=\sqrt{x}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $[0,+\infty)$?

Comment: for every $y \in [0,\infty)$ you can find $x=\frac {6+y^2} {2}$ such that $f(x)=y$, Can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2x-6}$$
$$g(x)=\sqrt x$$

Now, what is similarity in $f,g$?

If we substitute $x=(u+6)/2$ in $f$ we get $g(u)$

(Also square root function is always positive.So we get the +ve numbers only)

But $y^2=x$ have soltion $y=\pm \sqrt x$, but $f$ being a function is defined as $y+\sqrt x$. Yields only the positive part.